# ExtJS: keyboard focus specific context menu item

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

Currently I'm opening a [context menu](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu) following the strike of a keyboard shortcut.

How do I focus on (and select/highlight) a particular [menu item](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.menu.Item) of the context menu? So that then the item's handler can be executed by hitting the return key. I'm running ExtJS 4.1.

This what I'm currently doing:

```
myMenu.showBy(divElement); // divElement is a DOM object
myMenu.items.items[2].focus(); // focus on 3rd menu item
myMenu.doConstrain(); // move floating component into a constrain region
```

Still, focus is maintained on the menu element itself.

Comment: I haven't tried but according to the documentation Ext.menu.Item has a `focus()` method, just like any Ext.Component.

Comment: @AndreKR How I wish it was that simple. I will add more detail to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look into the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Menu2.html#Ext-menu-Menu) reveals that this is done using the `setActiveItem()` method:

```
var the_menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
  items: [
    {
      itemId: 'foo',
      text: 'Foo'
    },
    {
      itemId: 'bar',
      text: 'Bar'
    }
  ]
}).showBy(document.getElementById('some_div'));

the_menu.setActiveItem(the_menu.down('#bar'));
```

Note that this method is *private*, however `canActivateItem(item)` and `deactivateActiveItem(andBlurFocusedItem)` are *public*, so it's probably just an oversight.

Comment: Thanks; can't possibly imagine why such a useful method is *private*. +1ed and marked correct.

Comment: Incredible stuff; this works perfectly in Chrome, in Firefox it automatically triggers the handler associated with the menuitem which is set active by `setActiveItem()` function!

Comment: Can't reproduce that. http://jsfiddle.net/MnVUb/ Maybe you bound it to an enter keydown event and forgot to cancel the default action?

Comment: I modified my code to access menuitem via `down` as you are doing (was retrieving menu item by index) and I still have the same problem; I'm using Firefox 16.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: I suggest you open another question where you post some of your code and possibly a JSfiddle that shows the problem. It's important how your code is invoked.